# How to deal best with own question which ist totally off the track?

Tags: discussion

I have a question over here

[MS Flow: ticks function behaves different if fed with a string than with a string variable containing the same string](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/282112/ms-flow-ticks-function-behaves-different-if-fed-with-a-string-than-with-a-strin)

In the meantime the problem solved itself more or less miraculously and I no longer can't track it down.
Most likely (90%) I was just unable to correctly use the GUI of MS Flow to analyse the processed data. I think I did not understand how to look at the individual cycles of a loop to find the errors in question properly. So I probably missed that in one single case a date taken from another list might have been unintialised, which could explain the errors. But as it tends to happen, I don't have any proof that this was the root cause. Nevertheless the problem is gone now and I doubt it will rise it's head again, soon.

What to do with this question now?

- Add an answer on my own, which can only answer 90% of the question?
- Delete the question?
- Accept the first answer which held one interesting link?
- Radically editing my question, i.e. marking everything which had nothing to do with the root cause as irrelevant and adding my ramblings about what I possibly did wrong?

What could be best for the community?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to SE meta! Please, find the below answers for your questions:

**Add an answer on my own, which can only answer 90% of the question?**

> Yes, It's strongly recommended to add your own answer to be helpful for new visitors as well as to be a reference for you in case you face this issue in the future.

**Delete the question?**

> No, no need to delete your question even you didn't receive any answers,
> In the future, you may find the solution to your question, so you can add it to be helpful for all new visitors, as well as maybe someone faces the same issue and has a solution, so it would be a good opportunity to add his findings to your question.

**Accept the first answer which held one interesting link?**

> Of course, we encourage members to upvote all helpful answers if it guides you in the right direction and marks the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.

**Radically editing my question,**

> Editing the question is only required to add additional information that may help SE members to understand your question and thus help you faster.
> Also, you can edit your question if you have typo error, fix format ...etc

In your case, I would prefer to add your answer and mark it as answer! then appreciate all other answers by clicking upvote in case, these answers guide you in the right direction.